# C# linking hint with a random word from dictionary

Tags: c#

I am displaying parts of a word by using:

```
 public string GetPartialWord(string word)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(word))
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
        char[] partialWord = word.ToCharArray();
        int numberOfCharsToHide = word.Length / 2;
        Random randomNumberGenerator = new Random();
        HashSet<int> maskedIndices = new HashSet<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCharsToHide; i++)
        {
            int rIndex = randomNumberGenerator.Next(0, word.Length);
            while (!maskedIndices.Add(rIndex))
            {
                rIndex = randomNumberGenerator.Next(0, word.Length);
            }
            partialWord[rIndex] = '_';
        }
        return new string(partialWord);
    }
```

Therefore: the word game would look like: _a_e

I am thinking of making adding a hint button to display another character. Any ideas on how to proceed?

G_m_ -> Hint -> G_me

Comment: can you made your question more clear ?

Comment: @Vladimir, I apologize for the question being so vague. All I want to do is add a hint button to add another letter to my partial word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
public string GetWordAfterHint(string wordToProcess, string originalWord)
{
    List<int> emptyIndexes = new List<int>();
    for (int a = 0; a < wordToProcess.Length; a++)
    {
        if (wordToProcess[a] == '_')
        {
            emptyIndexes.Add(a);
        }
    }

    // in case if word doesn't have empty positions
    if (emptyIndexes.Count == 0)
    {
        return wordToProcess;
    }

    Random random = new Random();
    var indexForLetter = random.Next(emptyIndexes.Count);

    // create stringBuilder from string, because string is immutable and you can't change separate symbol
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(wordToProcess); 

    // insert symbol from originalWord in empty previously generated position
    sb[emptyIndexes[indexForLetter]] = originalWord[emptyIndexes[indexForLetter]]; // 

    //convert stringBuilder to string and return
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Method returns word after hint - if as `wordToProcess` you pass `"_a_e"` and as `originalWord` `"game"` then method returns `ga_e` or `_ame`.

Comment: @CodingYoshi I tried your method and it worked. Thanks yet again for your suggestions and insight. I am trying out Roma's method, however without success. I think I am writing something wrong from my side. Thanks Roma, I will implement this if it works as it is relatively shorter !

Comment: could you please explain the following lines please @Roma?                                                             

`StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(wordToProcess);
    sb[emptyIndexes[indexForLetter]] = originalWord[emptyIndexes[indexForLetter]];`

Comment: @UnknownR, see edited answer, I added short comments.

Comment: Hi @Roma forgive me for my lack of knowledge however I am still having trouble with implementing this piece of code. The partial word as seen from my code which I posted above is remaining the same when I press the hint button. What should I add to my hinttextBox.Text in order to get another character showing ?

Comment: The partial word does not change, so no. However I think that your code is correct, I am just not adding anything to my hintTextBox.Text , and that is why the word remains the same even though I press the hint button.

Comment: I am using `hintTextBox.Text = GetWordAfterHint(word[new Random().Next(word.Length)]);` , to display the word after hint once I have the random ready from my dictionary, with an error saying No argument given that corresponds to the formal parameter 'originalWord'

Comment: But yoh pass only one argument to the method. My implementation needs two parameters: first - word with missed letters, second - the same word but with all letters. In example, you should call this method with word `"game"` by this way: `hintTextBox.Text = GetWordAfterHint("_a_e", "game");`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132701/discussion-between-unknownr-and-roma).

Answer (score 1):

Store the indexes of the characters displayed in an array or list. When the hint button is pressed, compute a random index. Compare that index with the indexes of letters already being displayed, and recalculate a new random index if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

An Object Oriented approach:

From your `GePartialWord` method, return an instance of this class instead of a simple string:

```
public class GameWord
{
    public string OriginalWord { get; set; }
    public string GuessWord { get; set; }

    public string Hint()
    {
        int index = this.GuessWord.IndexOf('_');
        if (index != -1)
        {
            var builder = new StringBuilder(this.GuessWord);
            builder[index] = this.OriginalWord[index];

            this.GuessWord = builder.ToString();

            return this.GuessWord; // if needed
        }

        // No more hints, the world has no underscores
        return this.GuessWord;
    }
}
```

So in your method you will do this instead:

```
public GameWord GetPartialWord(string word)
{
    // The rest of your code

    // Change this line return new string(partialWord);
    // to this 
    return new GameWord{ OriginalWord = word, GuessWord = new string(partialWord)};
}
```

And in your form, create a private field like this:

```
private GameWord currentGameWord;
```

When you have the random word, call your `GetPartialWord` method and store the returned word in `currentGameWord`:

```
this.currentGameWord = GetPartialWord(someWord);
```

And because the method now returns an object, bind your textbox like this:

```
this.textBox1.Text = this.currentGameWord.GuessWord;
```

And in your button's click handler do this (your handler will have a different name):

```
private void HintButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.textBox1.Text = this.currentGameWord.Hint();
}
```